# python calculating average grade from a reading file

Tags: python

I have a file called 'students' and file contains name and grades. How can I find the average of grades for each students and print them as first column which is name and second column which is average grade?
This is the reading file

john 83 67 77

fred 66 55

ralph 86 99 95

nancy 30 70 90 44

anna 93 100 97

lisa 69 96 69

I have this so far:
with open('students','r') as f:

for line in f:

```
   for word in line.split():

     print(word)
```

with open('students','r') as f:

```
for line in f:

    int_list = [int(i) for i in line.split()]

    print int_list
```

Comment: Yay codecademy: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/32nm00/i_need_help_with_this_codecademy_lesson_it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fin = open("students","r")
for line in fin:
  line = line.split()
  if len(line) > 1:
    name = line[0]
    grades = map(float, line[1:])
    mean = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    print( "{:<10}: {:>5.2f}".format(name,mean) )
```